# European Zend Framework Hosting

Tags: zend-framework, hosting

Anybody know of any hosting companies with european servers that support the zend framework?

Answer (score 2):

Any host that supports recent version of PHP will suffice; Zend Framework is just a collection of PHP classes.

Comment: Just copy ZF to some folder on FTP and you'Re good to go. Only limitation is space. You will need around 200MBs for full ZF

Comment: Just FYI, a full download of ZF - including everything, is 101MB uncompressed. The library classes (which is all you need to include in your app) total 32MB.